# gRPC send oversized messages

Tags: c++, buffer, grpc

I'm using gRPC fetching messages from remote storage(eg, S3, GCS) and send it to client-side. Some of my messages are pretty large(about 500MB-1G), but the default send size for gRPC is only 4MB.

If I do `ServerReaderWriter->Write(message)` as usual, the write will fail.

Is there a good way to handle this problem?

Comment: gRPC is meant for command-and-control, not for transferring large amounts of data. Other protocols are more suitable for the latter; e.g. [Cloud storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)

Comment: It's not a "file", I read messages from files by some sorts, and transfer them in order gRPC. As for why I don't use HTTP GET, I need to support commands like pause and resume.

Comment: I suppose one thing you could do (if there isn't some better way) would be to chop up your data into 4MB (or smaller) chunks and send each chunk in a separate message, and have the receiver concatenate the data back together at the end.

Comment: Yes, if no better ways have to do this :(

Comment: If both sender and receiver of these large messages can afford to buffer the whole 1GB in memory for each of these fetches, then the max receive message size (which defaults to 4MB) can be increased to allow that.

Comment: If increasing the max received message size isn't possible or desirable, then splitting up the data and sending it in small chunks is indeed a recommended approach (chunking large data is one of the intended use cases for "streaming" RPCs in gRPC).

Comment: I've tried to increase buffer size
``builder.SetMaxSendMessageSize(1024*1024*1024);
  builder.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(1024*1024*1024);``
 but still fails. Why?